# Enumerable.Zip to enforce same lengths

Tags: c#, linq

I found myself frequently need to use `Enumerable.Zip()`, but having it to ensure the two `IEnumerable`s to have the same length (or both to be infinite). E.g., if one enumerable reaches the end but the other doesn't, I want it to throw. According to the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), Zip() will just stop enumerating as soon as one of them comes to the end.

I ended up always need something like below. What's the most "built-in"/elegant way to address this?

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<int> a, IEnumerable<int> b)
{
    // caching them. they are not huge or infinite in my scenario
    var a = a.ToList();
    var b = b.ToList();

    if (a.Count() != b.Count())
    {
        throw ...;
    }

    Enumerable.Zip(a, b, ...);
}
```

Comment: I suggest EquiZip from MoreLINQ: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/#equizip

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would probably just reimplement `Zip` the way you want to. It's really pretty simple - the following is trivially adapted from MoreLINQ. You'll want to give it a better name, mind you...

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipForceEqual<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
    if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
    if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

    return ZipForceEqualImpl(first, second, resultSelector);
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipForceEqualImpl<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (e2.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequences differed in length");
            }
        }
        if (e2.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequences differed in length");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I like this solution. While this is definitely an elegant solution, It's not always preferred to create a utility class or reference to a utility assembly in my development situation. That's why I was also looking for a more "built-in" way to address it.

Comment: Good solution but it might have a disadvantage if the result selector is a time or resource consuming operation, or the operation making changes in a database or an external data source. It could consume resources or make unrecoverable changes before it would find that the sequences are of different size. Which solution to pick, original from the question or this one, really depends on the result selector logic and requirements.

Comment: @KFL: Well, anything else is likely to end up iterating over the sequences more than once, without buffering all the results, significantly reducing its usefulness. Given that it's fairly simple, I'd definitely do it this way. It's handy to be able to write your own LINQ-like methods.

Comment: @Pavel: On the other hand, this copes with large sequences whereas the original doesn't. If you know that you *can* fit all the results in memory, you could always use this option with a trivial selector, call `ToList` on the results, and then perform the time/resource-consuming operation afterwards. Fundamentally you've got to either buffer data *or* cope with finding the error after using earlier results.

Comment: Seems a bit odd and a lot of typing to have `ZipForceEqualImpl`. Is there any reason for that or is that just the coding style of inherited from MoreLINQ?

Comment: @binki Couple of years late, but it's a pattern which allows `ZipForceEqual` to validate parameters and throw immediately at the point where it is called, rather than when enumeration of the result sequence begins. Use of `yield` in the `Impl` method turns it into an iterator, which means that all the code up until the first `yield` only runs when you try to enumerate the return value. So the outer (non-iterator) method does immediate validation, then defers to the iterator. Nowadays, C# has local functions which let you do this without having to expose the `Impl` code as a separate method.

Comment: @shambulator: Thanks for that - I must have missed the comment back in 2016 somehow!

Comment: @shambulator Thanks! I had forgotten about this post and I actually learned about that deferred exception throwing behavior in the meantime ;-).

Comment: @RoadRunner: It *is* private.